# images comparing

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to know what is the easiest way to compare between images. I found algorithms to see how much images look alike, but I just need to know if they are EXACTLY the same..

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: By "EXACTLY the same", do you mean every pixel even if they come from different sources?

Comment: 9 questions, zero accepts. I recommend reading the FAQ. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if they are 100% the same, you could just convert a `UIImage` to `NSData` and use `isEqualToData:`.  But if even a single pixel is the tiniest bit different, you won't get confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean equal to a human observer or exactly equal data pixel for pixel.  The first is hard, the second is easy.